# Applescript - AppleEvent handler failed on set properties {visible messages: }

Tags: email, applescript

I have the following applescript working under Lion, but it returns this `Error: -10000. Mail got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.` error under Yosemite.

```
try
tell application "Mail"
    set theViewer to front message viewer
    set theMsg to messages of theViewer
    set msgList to {}
    repeat with thisMsg in theMsg
        if read status of thisMsg is false and flagged status of thisMsg is false then
            set the end of msgList to thisMsg
        end if
    end repeat
    if msgList is {} then
        display dialog "There are no read messages in this mailbox."
    else
        tell theViewer to set properties to {visible messages:msgList}
    end if
end tell
on error the errMsg number the errNmb
if the errNmb is not -128 then
    set the errTxt to "Error: " & the errNmb & ". " & the errMsg
    display dialog the errTxt buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1
else
    error number -128
end if

end try
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is "tell theViewer to set properties to {visible messages:msgList}" supposed to be doing?

Comment: Change the message viewer to only display the read messages.

Comment: Read? The rest of the script is looking for Unread… anyway, that's the bit it doesn't like. It doesn't want to coerce the property, though I can't figure why

Comment: I meant Unread. I have similar scripts for Read and Flagged.

Comment: I'm guessing the visibility flag has changed, it might even now be sandboxed & that's why it isn't working. Console throws "10/07/2015 14:32:11.591 Mail[340]: [<MessageViewer 0x7f870d068d40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key focusedMessages." I don't know how to fix it, but that does seem a very roundabout way of finding unread & unflagged.

Comment: Yeah you might be right. My email workflow is based on filtering out the read from the unread in my inbox. Can you suggest another option?

Comment: A lot of Googling tells me that the 'visible messages' flag is totally broken :( Why not just sort by flagged, then unread, that would quickly sort to the top, unread first, followed by flagged [as the sorts are cumulative] I could throw up a little script that would tell you the counts too, if you needed.

Comment: That would be great and I would consider that an answer/solution to my question.

Comment: Cool, just posting now, hope you like it, as a compromise.

Comment: I tightened up the question title, too, for future Googlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments…

As it would appear that many people across the net are struggling & failing to get `set properties to {visible messages:msgList}` to work at all, it might be simpler in the long run to just pop up a count of unread/unflagged messages & optionally sort by flagged then unread for easy discovery in the Mail window.

I added in a 'sort by date or flags/unread' option in the dialog, too

```
tell application "Mail"
    tell the front message viewer
        set unReadMsgs to every message whose read status is false and flagged status is false
        display dialog ("There are " & (count of unReadMsgs) as string) & ¬
            " Unread/Unflagged messages." buttons {"Sort Unread", "Sort Date"} ¬
            default button "Sort Date" giving up after 300
        set theResult to button returned of result as string
        if theResult is "Sort Date" then
            set properties to {sort column:date received column}
        else if theResult is "Sort Unread" then
            set properties to {sort column:flags column}
            set properties to {sort column:message status column}
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```